# Use of extended ASCII as separator with python and pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I need to store a pandas dataframe in a csv file in utf-8 with the separator ☼. The problem is that it's an extended ASCII so I have this error:

`TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string`

I tried several things like to put **u'☼'** or to put in an **str object** but none of them work.

I work with Python 2.7.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try `to_csv` with param `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: You can't do this in Python 2, only in Python 3, as there is no encoding for that codepoint that uses just one byte. And ugh, there is no such thing as 'extended ASCII'.. Any site where you see that term is usually talking about one or other Windows 8-bit codepage.

Comment: Time to upgrade to `python 3` (if possible). ;)

Comment: All my calls to `to_csv` method have encoding param with `utf-8` value. I saw it works with Python 3 but I can't change my Python version :/. Is there no way to do this with Python 2.7 ?

Comment: My solution for a similar issue was writing my own implementation of `to_csv()`.